# Using sqrtf() in C: "undefined reference to `sqrtf'"

Tags: c, linux, math.h, geany

I am using Linux, [Ubuntu 12.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin), and Geany for coding. The code I am writing in C worked completely fine until I used the sqrtf command to find the square root of a float.

> Error: HAC3.c:(.text+0xfd7): undefined reference to `sqrtf' .

The part of code I am using sqrtf() in:

```
float syn(float *a, float *b, int dimensions)
{
    float similarity=0;
    float sumup=0;
    float sumdown=0;
    float as=0;
    float bs=0;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<dimensions; i++)
    {
        sumup = sumup + a[i] * b[i];
        as = as + a[i] * a[i];
        bs = bs + b[i] * b[i];
    }
    sumdown = sqrtf(as) * sqrtf(bs);
    similarity = sumup / sumdown;
    return similarity;
}
```

I included math.h, but this doesn't seem to be the problem.

Is there a way to fix Geany so this won't come up again?

Comment: sqrtf since c99. and linker option. e.g `gcc prog.c -std=c99 -lm`

Comment: For future reference: if something doesn't compile/link: have a look at **man -k <broken function>**, in your case **man -k sqrtf** ... it will tell you how to use it.

Comment: what is man -k sqrtf?

Comment: man -k is a more concise form of apropos.  Surely you weren't asking what a man page is, right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to `Build` -> `Set Build Commands` then under `C commands` click on the empty label and it will let you specify a new label (name it `Link`). Type in it `gcc -Wall -o "%e" "%f" -lm` - where `-lm` will tell it to link the `math` library to your app. Click `OK`.

Then click on `Build` and select your newly created label - `Link`. This should do it for you.

Comment: This is the perfect answer for my question. Thank you sir :)

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)

Comment: It's good to note that the -lm flag has to be specified after the files. I had a bug caused by doing this incorrectly.

Answer (score 9):

You need to link with `-lm` to provide the math functions.

Comment: how can i exactly link -lm in geany? I am sorry but my knowledge is little

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the many fine answers here, the portable form of the command that supports C99 version of `<math.h>` is [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//utilities/c99.html) as `c99 -l m`.  That having been said, every important Linux compiler supports `-lm`.